# jQuery coverflow like script?

Tags: jquery, photo, carousel

I am looking for a javascript (preferably jQuery) script that will simulate a coverflow like effect - but not quite like a coverflow. I made a simple example of what i am trying to achive here:

[alt text http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/7296/exampleh.gif](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/7296/exampleh.gif)

The black is the main image currently in focus - there is a prev and next link directly next to the main photo. The 2 purple boxes illustrate the previous and next image. They are slightly faded out, and the part which is under/in the black frame is hidden, so only part of the image is vissible. There can only be 3 images vissible at the time, and only one image fully vissible (the on in the middle).

i have tried looking at the jQuery carousel, and some coverflow plug-ins - but none that i have found seems to be able to fit these needs - anyone in here got an idea or a link to some code that would prodice the above mentioned?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to look at [jcoverflip](http://www.jcoverflip.com/demo), which resembles the Coverflow effect quite nicely

Answer (score 0):

I've just pushed pre-release of of my script: http://droganov.github.com/Coffee-Flow/

About:
CoffeeFlow is simple and powerful coverflow component that is able to easily rotate thousands of images. Coffeeflow works with css3-compatible browsers including mobile browsers, has opera fallback and compatibility mode for older browsers.

Coffeeflow supports touch events and gestures (tap, drag, and swipe) automatically as you connect hammer.js library.

Coffeeflow has built-in image preloader that also handles image load errors.

CoffeeFlow is designed to be used as a Class and has jQuery wrapper. JQuery is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try jCoverFlow2.0, I have tested over 1000 images and it works perfectly.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcoverflow/

and here is complete detail of it http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqueryuicoverflow/